# Installing Civicrm session_start(): error fatal

Tags: error, installation, cms-integration

I installed Civicrm on Wordpress on the plugin folder and I can't active it.

I have this error :

> Warning: session_start(): user session functions not defined in
>   /srv/bindings/code/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 282
>   Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module:
>   user (path: ) in /srv/code/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on
>   line 282

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your hosting provider or server config has overridden the PHP ini setting [`session.save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) (or related settings like `session.save_path`).

You could try applying a fix similar to the one over on [CRM-17212: IPN and other scripts break on Pantheon due to session handler](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17212)